# Increasing memory

Tags: luatex, texlive, compiling, memory

I am working on a document which produces ~4000 pages, each with at least 30 graphics per page. There is a lot of font switching and colouring different characters different colours. I am able to limit the pages outputted, which allows me to successfully compile. I'm using MikTex 64-bit but noticed the same problem when attempting through texLive.

However, when I attempt to increase the number of pages beyond a certain amount, LuaLaTex quits with:

```
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=493869].
<argument> ...ter {\reserved@b Pianos/256px/F/Piano_482.png} 
                                                  \ifeof \@inputcheck \else ...

l.33572 ...m]{{Pianos/256px/F/Piano_482.png}}F ♮3}
                                                   & \textcolor{F-Lt}{F} &  ...

 47374 words of node memory still in use:
   972 hlist, 276 vlist, 615 rule, 1 adjust, 7 disc, 276 local_par, 7 dir, 4 ma
th, 1376 glue, 30 kern, 388 penalty, 96 unset, 596 glyph, 16 align_record, 3318
 attribute, 142 glue_spec, 1660 attribute_list, 14 temp, 1 align_stack, 4 if_st
ack, 1 pdf_dest, 3 pdf_action, 412 pdf_colorstack, 26 pdf_setmatrix, 26 pdf_sav
e, 26 pdf_restore nodes
   avail lists: 1:1,2:32136,3:1080,4:450,5:513,6:468,7:9915,8:39,9:4238,10:45,1
1:507
!  ==> Fatal error occurred, no output PDF file produced!
SyncTeX written on document.synctex.gz.
Transcript written on document.log.
```

I can't really post an MWE because I think the glitch comes mostly from including images thousands of times. I am trying to pass the command line option into `lualatex` with `-extra-mem-top=50000000`.

I did also try editing my textmf file but it didn't seem to actually change that magic number (493869) number of strings. I am also running the 64-bit version of the binaries because I read that it could help with the memory allocation but it did not actually change anything.

Comment: you say at the top that lualatex quits but then you say you use the pdftex command which do you want to use (this makes a big difference here as lualatex uses dynamic memory allocation and pdftex does not)

Comment: Indeed, I would like to know how this happens, since I am using luaLaTeX and I thought there cant happen situations like this. Mainly because of that I faved the question ...

Comment: then I suggest you edit the question not to mention pdftex!  but you have run out of string pool not main mem so in texmf.cnf that is  `max_strings_  not `extra_mem`  and possibly some of the others in teh string group % Max number of characters in all strings, including all error messages,
% help texts, font names, control sequences.  These values apply to TeX.
pool_size = 6250000
% Minimum pool space after TeX's own strings; must be at least
% 25000 less than pool_size, but doesn't need to be nearly that large.
string_vacancies = 90000
% Maximum number of strings.
max_strings = 500000
% min

Comment: I suspect from the form of your error message that you are using `\graphicspath` really I would not use that in your case that is multiplying your string usage by the one more than the number of items in the path list.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle I am sorry, I might have confused you Mr. Carlisle. I am not the original person who wrote the question, I am just very interested in knowing, what is the cause of the error posted by question author.

Comment: @TomášKruliš ah I didn't spot that you were not the OP, OK but yes filenames get held in the same hash table as definitions so referencing lots of files is like making lots of definitions (this probably seemed like a good way of handling character memory in 1979, today it's less obviously useful....)

Comment: @David Carlisle I did change this value for the non Lua engines because I was unsure whether ```pdftex``` or ```pdflatex``` where being called at some point. I kept reading from people that LuaLatex "dynamically allocated" memory so I thought that it must be coming from somewhere else like the other engines. I'll edit it though. Also the reason I'm using graphicspath is for colour schemes.

Comment: what do you mean by `I'm using graphicspath is for colour schemes`  ?

Comment: That way I can switch between colour and no colour, and dark background or light.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

LuaTeX uses dynamic memory allocation for main mem so the  `texmf.cnf` setting you are using would have no effect even if you set if for luatex rather than pdftex.

However it does still inherit some fixed array usage from classic tex, including the number of strings.

this produces the error that you state (note it is an infinite loop so it *relies* on an error condition to terminate.

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\loop
\iftrue
\advance\count0 1
\expandafter\def\csname zzz\the\count0\endcsname{}
\repeat
\end{document}
```

This produces

```
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 2.242 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./cc372.aux)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=493861].
```

You can increase the number of strings by calling it as follows (or by editing texmf.cnf)

```
$ max_strings=1000000 lualatex cc372
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./cc372.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 2.141 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./cc372.aux)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [hash size=665536].
<recently read> \endcsname
```

Now you see it has not run out of strings but has overflown the hash table, which could be similarly increased. You need to iterate on your real document to increase whatever is needed.

Here, if I increase the size of the hash table enough, it takes several seconds to run, but eventually runs out of strings again:

```
$ max_strings=1000000 hash_extra=1000000 lualatex cc372
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.10.0 (TeX Live 2019) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
(./cc372.tex
LaTeX2e <2019-10-01> patch level 3

luaotfload | main : initialization completed in 2.187 seconds
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2019/10/25 v1.4k Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/local/texlive/2019/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo)) (./cc372.aux)
! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=993861].
```

Comment: I'm using texWork and added what you have written as a command argument. Is that how ```cc372``` is supposed to be used? When I run this I get ```This is LuaTeX, Version 1.11.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) 
 restricted system commands enabled.
! I can't find file `max_strings=1000000'.
<*> max_strings=1000000 ```
Also I just want to point out that I will actually need about 5 or more times the capacity that I have, just to compile my current draft. If I had about 20 times more, I could actually finish expanding my format how I originally have designed it.

Comment: `cc732` is just the random filename I used in this answer (the 732rd answer I have posted since I started using cc prefix..)  as I commented under the question, you are almost certainly using more string space than needed so fixing that rather than allocating an ever bigger hash table is probably best. @TheRealDre

Comment: @TheRealDre also if you are using windows you may not be able to set the enviornment  variable on the same commandline as calling luatex (I don't know) it would be simpler to edit the texmf.cnf file also this answer was texlive, I assume miktex has the same settings but I have never used it. so you might need to check..

Comment: @TheRealDre Ulrike tells me that in miktex you can set this as an option to the command  so  the syntax is `lualatex --max-strings=.... filename` to process `filename.tex`

Comment: CarIisle I am using graphics path so I can switch between colour, greyscale, and also inverted colour (black paper). It would make me have to build my source tex 4 seperate times though rather than simply change my graphics directory.

This is what I get when I run when you you told me in command line (or actually passing as options in TexWorks. ```lualatex: warning: running with administrator privileges
This is LuaTeX, Version 1.11.2 (MiKTeX 2.9.7250 64-bit) 
 system commands enabled.
! I can't find file `max_strings=1000000'.
<*> max_strings=1000000 ```

Comment: Even when I tried it how Ulrike said (with the double dashes) it just gave me ```lualatex: unrecognized option '--max_strings=1000000'```

Comment: @TheRealDre I know nothing about miktex but you should be able to set it in the texmf.cnf that you said you changed in the question (assuming miktex reads texmf.cnf.  Anyhow that is the setting you need to change the miktex configuration documentation hopefully shows how to do that (but I still suspect that you do not need anything like that many strings)

Comment: @Carlisle I'm able to get the limit to `! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [hash size=2065536].` That did almost get me what I wanted, but I'm just shy by about 10%. Do you think that value is the maximum achievable? You may well be right about not needing that many strings. If I post the code which generates it I will need a lot of preamble to get it to run. Should I start a new topic or post this as a new reply?

Comment: @TheRealDre I have no idea, you could ask on the luatex list (the luatex developers are not usually on this site, but also you never showed your macro code, it is highly likely that you can use far fewer cs names. Unless it is really true that your document really is the document with the most tex commands defined in 40 years worth of global tex use, which is possible but.....

Answer (score 1):

editing `lualatex.ini` to use the values David Carlisle suggested, then rebuilding formats did the trick. I'm happy.

my `lualatex.ini` file:

```
main_memory=12000000
pool_size=4250000
max_strings=8000000
hash_extra=1000000
```

To find the path I opened the MikTeX Console and went Settings > Directory > (then the one labelled config). Open that folder and then you go `./miktex/config/lualatex.ini` from there. Thanks!