# How to increase memory limit in LuaHBTeX (near-duplicate)

Tags: luatex, memory, luahbtex

This question is essentially a reiteration of [Increasing memory](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/518492/increasing-memory) which I posted. I was satisfactorily able to get the magic numbers (`! TeX capacity exceeded, sorry [number of strings=480992]`) up to about 2000000 at that time. Although I would really appreciate being able to go further than this, I was able to make this work.

The issue is that since `MikTeX` updated, it changed the `lualatex` engine to `luahbtex`. I was able to make it run again with the suggestion at [lualatex no longer works.. because the memory dump file could not be found](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/536709/lualatex-no-longer-works-because-the-memory-dump-file-could-not-be-found)

It would be nice if the installer updated these things for you or at least told you about it. Even googling `luahbtex` doesn't return much.

Anyway, now I could at least use lualatex, but now the lualatex.ini file that I had changed to be

```
main_memory=12000000
pool_size=4250000
max_strings=8000000
hash_extra=1000000
```

now it doesn't apparently do that anymore.. I still get the same default `magic` number. I did try to redo the instructions like rebuilding formats and stuff but no luck. If my voice matters I want to say that LaTeX would be even better if memory was either a little easier to change or if the memory could possibly default to being higher. Some argue that you don't need that much memory but I am saying yes I do. Imagine a document with lots of formatting being changed many times per page with many pages. If I had unlimited memory the things I could do with my project would be amazing. Already in my bigger document I have disabled certain things like font switching and graphics to make it fit under `magic number = 2000000`. I can't however make it fit under the default half a million. Ideally (it may be ridiculous) I would have more like `2000000000` amount of `magic`.

Or is there another `TeX` engine with unlimited `magic`? I actually switched from XeLaTeX to LuaLaTeX because it's more `magical` although it's slower I didn't mind as I was able to transcend the spell level I had at the time. I would be willing for it to be another 10x slower for 10x more `magic`. Does something called superultrafatTeX exist?

If anyone wants to prove me wrong, I'd be willing to show my output, as well as the code to prove that one actually needs this mass of `magic`. A wizard such as myself requires spells like this.

I know I can use externalisation, however, this adds complexity in that I already have everything going to the right page in toc and pdf bookmarks and margins.

Maybe someone could point me in the right direction for rendering one page at a time? I guess if I divide it into pages I would technically have at least 2000 times as much `magic` per page. I would just need maybe some slight wizardry to make that spell cast? This would leave me with at least 500x as much `magic` as my currently most advanced spells use. Thanks in advance, whatever the solution may be. Remember, without splitting, I need at least 2000000 `magic`.

Comment: I just tried. I opened the lualatex.ini with `initexmf --edit-config-file lualatex.ini` added a `max_strings` entry and recreated the format. The numbers changed, as I could see in a log. Beside this: latex is not responsable for the memory of the engine. Also I'm quite sure that you are wasting unnessarly memory.

Comment: its rather rare to use up _strings_ by having more pages or more tikz images and fonts only used a limited number of strings per font (the filename etc) and switching fonts doesn't use more, so what are you doing in the document that us using up so much string space?

Comment: unfortunately I have never been able to get my output-ability back.. I'm sad. I wish I had not updated. Once I get it working I promise never to update again.. :(
Maybe someone would be willing to look at my code and explain to me how it is that I'm wasting memory.. or how I could go back to the higher numbers. I did what you said but my numbers did not rise.